# Promisfy CoffeeScript Class

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have such CoffeeScripted class:

```
class Hair
  truncate: () ->
    DoAsyncStuffWithMyDB ->
      console.log "Async Stuff With My DB completed"
```

Now I want to use this class, e.g.:

```
doghair = new Hair
doghair
.truncate()
.then(() ->
    #do stuff
)
```

How do I use Bluebird do achieve such?

Comment: Does DoAsyncStuffWithMyDB already return a promise? If it's not you need to [promisify](stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) it

Comment: What arguments does `DoAynscStuffWithMyDB()` take?  To promisify something, one needs to know what arguments it takes.  If it follows the node.js async calling convention, then you can use Bluebird's `promisify()` function.  If not, you have to do make a custom wrapper to return a promise that is properly resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is achieved the custom way:

```
Promise  = require('bluebird')
class Hair
  truncate: () ->
    new Promise((resolve, reject) ->
      DoAsyncStuffWithMyDB.create data, (err,res) ->
        if err
          reject err
        else
          resolve true
    )
```

Now your instantiated object is `then`-able. Congrats!